# Magento2 Google Webmaster tools "image" field is missing

Tags: magento2.3.7

I have a problem that I do not know how to solve. I have been looking for a solution for more than a week. I have a new store built on Magento, and when I add my store to Google Archive, this problem appears for me

image" field is missing